# Reverse for loop not working in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, for-loop, reverse

When I am trying to use Reverse for loop in PostgreSQL, it seems the compiler is not recognizing `REVERSE`. It skips the loop completely.

```sql
DO $$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'LOOP STARTING......';
  FOR I IN REVERSE 1..10 LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'INSIDE LOOP......';
    RAISE NOTICE 'NUMBER IS  %', I;
  END LOOP;
END $$;
```

> OUTPUT
> -------------------
> NOTICE:  LOOP STARTING......

But when I omit `REVERSE`, the compiler works fine.
Any idea why this is happening.

I am using PgAdmin version 1.20.0.

Comment: If you choose reverse, you have to revese `10` with `1` too

Comment: Actually, it does run the loop, but it sees that the start condition 1 is already lower than the end condition 10, so it stops. It's just like if you ran `FOR I IN 10..1`. The "compiler" has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Also, `pgadmin` has nothing to do with this. It's merely a tool for connecting with `Postgres` databases

Answer (score 8):

If you choose [`REVERSE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html), you have to revese `10` with `1` too. So you have to replace :

```
FOR  I IN  REVERSE  1..10 LOOP
```

By

```
FOR  I IN  REVERSE  10..1 LOOP
```

Answer (score 0):

[The doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-INTEGER-FOR) says below:

> If the lower bound is greater than the upper bound (or less than, in the REVERSE case), the loop body is not executed at all. No error is raised.

So, these two below work:

```sql
DO $$
BEGIN
  FOR num IN 1..3 LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', num;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

```sql
DO $$
BEGIN
  FOR num IN REVERSE 3..1 LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', num;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

But, these two below don't work:

```sql
DO $$
BEGIN
  FOR num IN 3..1 LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', num;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

```sql
DO $$
BEGIN
  FOR num IN REVERSE 1..3 LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', num;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys for your help.

I am facing one more issue.

As per your suggestion i have sorted out my Concept on Reverse for loop..

I am Trying to reverse number let say '1234' using reverse for loop in PgAdmin.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
L_NO VARCHAR(5) := '1234';
L_LEN NUMERIC(5);
L_REV_NO VARCHAR(5);
BEGIN
L_LEN := CHAR_LENGTH(L_NO) ;
RAISE NOTICE 'STRING LENGTH IS %' , L_LEN  ;
FOR  CNTR IN  REVERSE  L_LEN..1 LOOP
   L_REV_NO = L_REV_NO||SUBSTRING(L_NO,CNTR,1);
END LOOP;
RAISE NOTICE 'NUMBER IS %' ,L_NO ;
RAISE NOTICE 'REVERSE NUMBER IS %' ,L_REV_NO ;
END $$ ;
```

---

### OUTPUT

```
NOTICE:  STRING LENGTH IS 4
NOTICE:  NUMBER IS 1234
NOTICE:  REVERSE NUMBER IS <NULL>
```

Why the reverse number is coming as `<Null>`. 
even I checked SUBSTRING  func Synatx its correct?

Comment: If you are facing another issue you should post a separate question on SO, not an answer to your actual question, but just so you know, if you use concatenation operator `||` in Postgres, and any of your value is `NULL`, then the result will be `NULL`. Initialize it as an empty string, or use `CONCAT` instead.